# Firestore security rules - Property resource is undefined on object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

For some reason when I try to use the resource.data I get an error saying that resource is undefined. In this case it occurs in the notUpdating() function. Why is this and how can I fix it?

I'm new to firebase - Thanks for the help!

**Error:** simulator.rules line [12], column [28]. Property resource is undefined on object.

**Rules:**

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        function authed() {
          return request.auth != null
        }
        function matchesUser() {
          return request.auth.uid == userId
        }
        function notUpdating(field) {
            return !(field in request.resource.data) || resource.data[field] == request.resource.data[field]
        }
    
        match /folders/{docId} {
          allow read: if authed() && matchesUser()
          allow create: if authed() && matchesUser()
        }
        match /files/{docId} {
          allow read: if authed() && matchesUser()
          allow create: if authed() && matchesUser()
          allow update: if authed() && matchesUser() && notUpdating("userId")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**My code for adding and updating a file:**

```js
function addFile() {
  if (!filePathInp.value) return;

  const fileName = filePathInp.value.split("\\").pop();
  const fileRef = ref(storage, `users/${$user.uid}/files/${fileName}`);
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(fileRef, filePathInp.value);

  uploadTask.on(
    "state_changed",
    (snapshot) => {},
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      // upload complete
      getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
        const files = collection(firestore, `users/${$user.uid}/files`);
        const filesQuery = query(
          files,
          where("name", "==", fileName),
          where("userId", "==", $user.uid),
          where("parentPath", "==", path)
        );

        getDocs(filesQuery).then((doc) => {
          if (doc.empty) {
            addDoc(files, {
              url: downloadURL,
              name: fileName,
              createdAt: new Date(),
              parentPath: path,
              userId: $user.uid,
            });
          } else {
            updateDoc(doc.docs[0].ref, {
              url: downloadURL,
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  );

  filePathInp.value = "";
}
```